# For new user how to create and share private key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS and referring to

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html ( **Managing User Accounts on Your Linux Instance** )

In this page it mentions

> "..The user should now be able to log into the newuser account on your
>   instance using the private key that corresponds to the public key that
>   you added to the authorized_keys file..."

who will create private key for new users and how to share with them ?

Comment: This is more related to SSH than AWS. You must not share private keys, never. Each user must create a SSH key pair and put(or give if you're the admin) the public key to put on AWS IAM. Then they use there private key to connect to AWS service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend asking the user to share his public key, instead of creating key to your end, then add the user-key in the `authorized_keys` of your instance.

By this way, user private key will be safe and you will able to grant access to the user but what if you want to remove user and revoke his access?

So then [opswork manage ssh](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/security-ssh-access.html) for you, If the user in the same account you should better to explore [OpsWork](https://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/) which handle user access fo instances and stack.

You can easily grant and revoke access to any user.

[image]

[/registered-instances-register](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/registered-instances-register.html)